# Is 25p/s a normal speed for JtR?

Tags: password-recovery

I usually encrypt documents I create and store their password in a file. But when I wanted to access one of my Office-PowerPoint files `.pptx`, realized  that I forgot to save its password.

The only thing I remember is that it was probably an 8-digit (random) number. So I extracted its hash using Office2john and then, created a text file and wrote any number between 1000 and 10^8 in it, and used it as a wordlist with John the Ripper.

mainhash.txt:
`$office$*2013*100000*256*16*3af1c16df63e1b9acb2f47722b3dbf08*bc4b8dc516f81d350e4cefbe7e3958b3*2d17d23feda858b00f48e21e5a9b982d044cbe281f5e668c496e5b0bd7bc26dc`

number-list.eight:

```
1000
1001
...
99999999
```

then:

```
john-the-ripper --wordlist=number-list.eight mainhash.txt
```

But it is **too** slow (25p/s). With this speed, it can take more than 45 days to crack that (simple?) password!

I'm running John the Ripper on a Linux virtual machine (lubuntu 20.04.3), which has 1213MB of RAM. The host machine is core i5-2430 2.4 GHz with 4GB of memory.

I know my machine is weak, but is it THAT weak?! Is 25p/s really normal for a system like mine?

Can I do anything to *dramatically* increase its speed? (I mean isn't 45 days a bit **too** long?!)

Comment: I believe this post IS on topic here but you might get better responses from security.stackexchange.com.  I would have intuitively thought 25 p/s is very low. (although that is a 10 year old laptop cpu). You might want to check its not throttling, using both threads or spin up a cloud server to crack it   There are likely better ways of specifying to test all numerical passwords without having to read a password file (eg john -i digits...)